# How to convert list of jsons in a nested list of jsons to csv in python?

Tags: python, json, csv

How do I convert a **list of jsons in a nested list of jsons** to be in the following format? Can't seem to get this right and many examples use `pandas` where as I'd prefer to use `csv.DictWriter`. My thoughts are to (in a loop) read the json - in this case `data`, transpose it for it to be horizontal.

```
{"rows": [
        {
          "data": [
            {
              "A": "1",
              "B": "2"
            },
            {
              "C": "3",
              "D": "4"
            },
            {
              "E": "5",
              "F": "6"
            }
          ]
        },
       ...
       ...
       ...
        {
          "data": [
            {
              "A": "7",
              "B": "8"
            },
            {
              "C": "9",
              "D": "10"
            },
            {
              "E": "11",
              "F": "12"
            }
          ]
        }
]
}
```

Desired format:

```
A, B, C, D, E, F
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
...
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
```

I've read the json already using `json.loads`. Just stuck on converting this bit.

Comment: is there really a subdict for A,B, and another for C,D =

Comment: Yeah there is @FloLie

Comment: I suggest using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DictWriter` is pretty straightforward with a dict comprehension to generate the row data:

```py
import json
import csv

json_str = '''{"rows": [{"data": [{"A": "1", "B": "2"},
                                  {"C": "3", "D": "4"},
                                  {"E": "5", "F": "6"}]},
                        {"data": [{"A": "7", "B": "8"},
                                  {"C": "9", "D": "10"},
                                  {"E": "11", "F": "12"}]}]}'''

data = json.loads(json_str)
with open('out.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames='ABCDEF')
    w.writeheader()
    for row in data['rows']:
        data = {k:v for d in row['data'] for k,v in d.items()}
        print(data)
        w.writerow(data)
```

Output (dict comprehension result):

```py
{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '4', 'E': '5', 'F': '6'}
{'A': '7', 'B': '8', 'C': '9', 'D': '10', 'E': '11', 'F': '12'}
```

out.csv:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F
1,2,3,4,5,6
7,8,9,10,11,12
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off not doing anything fancy. Just walk the dictionary and copy the data into a new one.

```
json_input = {}  # Your input JSON dictionary
transposed_data = {}
for row in json_input['rows']:
    for data_dict in row['data']:
        for key, value in data_dict.items():
            if key not in transposed_data:
                transposed_data[key] = []
            transposed_data[key].append(value)
```

Then you can just write out the data however you see fit. For example:

```
keys = transposed_data.keys()
num_values_per_key = len(transposed_data[keys[0]])
with open('output.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(f'{", ".join(keys)}\n')
    for index in range(num_values_per_key):
        values = []
        for key in keys:
            values.append(transposed_data[key][index])
        output_file.write(f'{", ".join(values)}\n')
```

It's also possible that some library providers a better way of making the CSV. I didn't spend much time here since it sounds like transposing is the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

In a just because it is possible manner I also want to show the list comprehension way of doing it. I am generally a great fan of the "pythonic way" of doing things, however in this case it does get a little messy.

```
import json      
import pandas as pd
json_data = '''{"rows": [
        {
          "data": [
            {
              "A": "1",
              "B": "2"
            },
            {
              "C": "3",
              "D": "4"
            },
            {
              "E": "5",
              "F": "6"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "data": [
            {
              "A": "7",
              "B": "8"
            },
            {
              "C": "9",
              "D": "10"
            },
            {
              "E": "11",
              "F": "12"
            }
          ]
        }
]
}'''
          
raw_data = json.loads(json_data)                  
                  
cleaned_data = [{key:val for subdict in row for key,val in subdict.items()} for row in [data["data"] for data in raw_data["rows"]]]

Out[118]: 
[{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '4', 'E': '5', 'F': '6'},
 {'A': '7', 'B': '8', 'C': '9', 'D': '10', 'E': '11', 'F': '12'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(cleaned_data)

Out[120]: 
   A  B  C   D   E   F
0  1  2  3   4   5   6
1  7  8  9  10  11  12
```